# Create access request for file using Google Drive REST API

Tags: google-drive-api

From:

https://support.google.com/drive/answer/6211862?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

If a file won’t open, a few things could be wrong:

The file owner didn’t give you permission to view the file.
You're signed in to a different Google Account.
Your access could be denied because someone removed your permission to view the file.

Is it possible to create access request using Google Drive REST API?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The owner of the file will be the one to grant you permission using [Permissions.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions/create) not the other way around. If you're thinking you can gain access to a restricted file using Drive API, not possible.

Comment: I'm not about gain access. When you visit file not shared with you, you can press the button `Access request` and owner will receive email. So, can I generate this letter using Google API, file id and my google credentials?

Comment: that feature is not yet present in the current API